# Reopen?: Ultimate 6-max cash game open raise chart without antes

Tags: discussion

[This Q](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/8833/88) has been dramatically altered after being closed/put-on-hold. I was wondering what the community's opinion was about whether to reopen it?

Comment: Keep it closed.